# WordPress: Change language of the splash screen

Tags: wordpress, wpml, maintenance-mode

I am using WPML and WP-maintenance-mode plugin on my site. This site supports dutch and english language with /en and /de in url as below.

```
mysite.com/blog/de/blabla
mysite.com/blog/en/blabla
```

When I put the site into maintenance mode, the maintenance mode screen with /en shows a message in English like:

```
Sorry for the inconvenience.
Our website is currently undergoing scheduled maintenance.
```

I want to display same message in Dutch when the site is accessed with /de.

But I am not sure how to configure this settings in WPML or Maintenance Mode plugin.

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have the **WPML String Translation** plugin (need license for it), you can locate those strings and translate them, with approximate steps like this:

- In your dashboard, go to *WPML > Theme and plugins localization*
- Select 'WP Maintenance Mode' in the plugin list and click on 'Scan selected plugins for strings'
- Go to *WPML > String Translation* and click on 'Translate texts in admin screens' at the bottom of the page
- Search for *wpmm_settings*
- Select the strings that you want to translate and click on 'Add to String translation' at the bottom
- Go to *WPML > String Translation*, search for *wpmm_settings* and add a translation for each string.

Documentation: https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/string-translation/finding-strings-that-dont-appear-on-the-string-translation-page/

Comment: Thanks for the instruction. But I did not understand the search for wpmm_settings settings. Where to search it?

Comment: In the document I shared there are some screenshots of the String Translation interface, for example [this one](https://cdn.wpml.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/cant-find-the-strings.png). At the top, there is a 'search for' text field and various filters. That's the search to use.